# How to have the same year in two date input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have two date input "`from`" and "`To`" I want the year in the input to be the same in both dates

Example :

1. If user chose in the "from" input "11/03/**2017**", he can choose in the "to" input until "31/12/**2017**"
2. If user chose in the "from" input "06/07/**2014**", he can choose in the "to" input until "31/12/**2014**"

(the year must not exceed or precede the year already selected)

And if user tries to select another year not present in the first input, we display some warning message.

```js
    $("#from").on("change", function() {
        validateYear();
        var from = $("#from").val();
        if (from) {
          var maxYear = new Date(from).getFullYear();
          $("#to").attr("max", maxYear+"-12-31");
          $("#to").attr("min", maxYear+"-01-01");
        }
    });

    $("#to").on("change", function(){
        validateYear();
    });

    function validateYear() {
        var from = $("#from").val();
        var to = $("#to").val();
        if(from && to && new Date(from).getFullYear() != new Date(to).getFullYear()) {
            $("#to").val("");
            alert("error");
        }
    }
```

```css
.from, .to {
    padding:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="from">From</span>
<input id="from" type="date">
<span class="to">To</span>
<input id="to" type="date">
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried that is not working correctly.

Comment: You might add a change listener to the first input and set the min and max values of the second input to 1 Jan and 31 Dec in the same year as the entered date. If the date in the second input doesn't fit the criteria, display a friendly warning.

Comment: @RobG thank you, I mostly needed ideas, I didn't know where I started, I'll try it

Comment: I don't know why the downvote or the close

Comment: Close votes have an associated reason. This type of question is quite broad as it involves a number of issues: attaching listeners, setting values, function logic, warnings, etc. all of which are covered in numerous other questions and answers. SO requires questions to focus on a single issue where the answer is applicable to others in the future.

Comment: Questions also need to show an effort on askers part to solve the issue themselves by doing research and not expecting us to write all the code for them.

Comment: Look into https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic logic would be:

```
    $("#from").on("change", function() {
        validateYear();
        var from = $("#from").val();
        if (from) {
          var maxYear = new Date(from).getFullYear();
          $("#to").attr("max", maxYear+"-12-31");
          $("#to").attr("min", maxYear+"-01-01");
        }
    });

    $("#to").on("change", function(){
        validateYear();
    });

    function validateYear() {
        var from = $("#from").val();
        var to = $("#to").val();
        if(from && to && new Date(from).getFullYear() != new Date(to).getFullYear()) {
            $("#to").val("");
            alert("error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This creates a usability issue as when a date is first entered in the first input, the user hasn't had time to enter a date in the second input so will almost always be shown the alert. Also, *getYear* returns a two digit year, so 1919 and 2019 will not show an error.

Comment: I ve tested it and it doesnt show the alert all the time because of this first check: `if(from && to &&...)`. Were you able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes, missed that. You might convert it to a runnable snippet. *getYear* needs to be fixed though.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck thank's for this, it's a bit like that but once he has selected the `from` date, It have to turn off the other years of the `to` input

Comment: @PЯINCƏ I have updated the answer to cover that.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck I'm testing, I'll feed back to you in few moment ;)

Comment: @TiagoBrenck where is `validateYear();` ? I have an validateYear is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to rename them. Fixed now

Comment: @TiagoBrenck If you chose example "from" `01/03/2017` and you type manually in "to" `10/02/2019`it shows the alert error in the `2` of 2019, Is there a way to wait user to enter the full date to display the error ?

Comment: You can check my update, It dont let me hit the full year in "to" input, It alert in the first number year

Comment: @TiagoBrenck despite the last point that blocked but I think you haven't had time, I thank you very much for your time and your help, it helped me a lot and advanced me. you're a warrior. Thanks again. I'll add you in linkedin if it doesn't bother you